# Using dynamic object fields with a strongly typed model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, geocoding

I am currently working with a nuget google geocoding api that returns a object with dynamic fields([specifically this one](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net)). Based on the input address, the return object often returns different fields. Is there an efficient manner in which i can go through the dynamic fields and match them up to my model without 100 if blocks?

Example:
Input: New York, NY

returns:
[image]

or
Input: 1600 West Pennsylvania Avenue

returns:
[image]

Model:

```
        public string streetnumber { get; set; }
        public string route { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string postalcode { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the package AutoMapper available in Nuget Gallery.

To install, open the Console Package Manager, select the project that you want to install the package and type: Install-Package AutoMapper

After that, you can use the method Mapper.DynamicMap to map objects from Geocoding API.

Below an example to clarify:

```
var order = new {CustomerName = "Bob Smith"};
var message = Mapper.DynamicMap<ICreateOrderMessage>(order);
message.CustomerName.ShouldEqual("Bob Smith");
```

If you have any doubt about the library, check out on http://automapper.org/

I hope it helps you. ;)